# warning message '+' not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, warnings

Using for self-defined variables, I am receiving the following error when trying to run odds ratio analysis.

```
dat1 <- escalc(measure="OR", ai=a, bi=b, ci=c, di=d, data=dat.turnover)
warnings(dat1)
```

> Warning messages:
>   1: In Ops.factor(ai, bi) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors 
>   Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
>     argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

All the data I am using for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are numeric.

Comment: even if they are numbers they could still be coded as factors. try to wrap them in as.numeric() and see if that fixes the error.

Comment: Try testing if the variable is a factor via `is.factor(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

Without having access to your data, the best I can say is that any attempt to sum `factor` variables (try checking their `str()` to ensure R knows they are numeric and hasn't factored them) will cause `NA` values to be imputed, or an exception. The only time I have seen this `Ops.factor()` error is when the data are factors and not numeric.

That said, to ensure numeric calculations (being mindful of what  [divibisan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8366499/divibisan) mentioned in the comments below) I would try:

```
dat.turnover$a <- as.numeric(as.character(dat.turnover$a))
dat.turnover$b <- as.numeric(as.character(dat.turnover$b))
dat.turnover$c <- as.numeric(as.character(dat.turnover$c))
dat.turnover$d <- as.numeric(as.character(dat.turnover$d))

dat1 <- escalc(measure="OR", ai=a, bi=b, ci=c, di=d, data=dat.turnover)
```

Comment: This could be dangerous: calling `as.numeric` on a factor returns the numeric code used to encode the values as a factor, not the value itself. So it's generally safer to do `as.numeric(as.character(...))` which will get the factors value and then try to convert that to a numeric